# 405 (Method Not Allowed), No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

> OPTIONS
>   http://cloud.algarytm.com:8000/webservices/rest/LP_LOGIN/get_login_status_f/
>   405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://cloud.algarytm.com:8000/webservices/rest/LP_LOGIN/get_login_status_f/'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: is cors enabled on the server?

Comment: [Krishna Manchikanti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15404763) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66758399) saying "This error occurs typically for mac and window users, if your using chrome all u need to do is [add the extension to ur chrome follow the instruction in the video, toggle on the extension and refresh current page through extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)"